# How can I show my videos section in my Facebook timeline, so other people can see my video section?

Tags: video, facebook-timeline

Long time ago, I can see Video section in my Facebook timeline, its contain all my uploaded video. Other people visiting my timeline can see this sections. Now, I can't see the video section in my timeline anymore, tried to find some option to enable it but not success. Is there a way to show my video section in the Facebook timeline?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not add a Videos section to the left column of your Facebook profile - the defaults are Intro, Photos, and Friends, and you cannot add any more.

One (very minor) thing you can do is to ensure that your videos are linked to from your profile. Check that a Videos link appears in the "More" drop-down menu right below your cover photo. It should look something like this:

[image: Facebook Timeline navigation options]

If you don't see the Videos link, you can click on "Manage Selections" and enable the Videos link from there.

Comment: I see the link :) Thank. But I think this is so sad.